# Flag stars are displaying out of order on some browsers

Tags: html, css

The stars on the flag are displaying out of order on certain browsers. I have been trying to fix it by changing some of the CSS code and HTML and nothing is working. It looks completely fine in my browsers. I tried adding \br\ to the stars to put in a break for each line and that is not helping.

```
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.american-flag {
  height: 26rem;
  width: 53rem;
  background-color: #B31C31;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.american-flag:before {
  content: '';
  height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 53rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4rem 0 white,
              0 8rem 0 white,
              0 12rem 0 white,
              0 16rem 0 white,
              0 20rem 0 white;
}

.american-flag:after {
  align-items: center;
  content: '★ ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ \00a0\200a ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ \00a0\200b ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ \00a0\200a ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ \00a0\200b ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ \00a0\200a ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ \00a0\200b ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ \00a0\200a ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ \00a0\200b ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ ★';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 14.1rem;
  margin-top: -4.3rem;
  width: 20.75rem;
  background: #39386E;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: .5rem;
  line-height: 1.55rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 30rem;
  background: #fff;
  border: #B31C31 solid 0.125rem;
  border-radius: 0.625rem;
  color: #39386E;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.btn:hover {opacity: 0.6}


#stage {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #000028;
}
```

This is how it is displaying on some browsers:

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVfH1.png)

I am using a Mac and it displays the way I want in Chrome and Safari. When pulled up in Chrome on a Windows PC it has the stars out of order. Here is a link to the Codepen [Codepen Project](https://codepen.io/bcaruthers04/pen/YoepWm?editors=0110)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the font-size of '#american-flag::after' to '2.2rem'. It should work.

I wonder why can't you use an image(preferably SVG).